# Time displayed in Logcat

Tags: android, time, android-logcat

I need to get the Android device timestamp in the format hh:mm:ss:SS. I am able to view the time displayed in the Logcat of Eclipse. Is it the computer's time or is it the Android device's time?

Comment: It's been the Android device's date and time in all the logcat logs I've taken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running your app on Android device then it will print device's time, if on emulator then it will show computer's time.

To be ensure just match the Log's time with device's time and with computer's time you will find your answer..

Comment: This is no longer the case at least since Android 5.x.

Answer (score 92):

From the [docs of logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) you can see that there is an option to specify how the output is formatted ([-v](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat)).

To get a timestamp, you can use the command

```
logcat -v time
```

This will prefix each message with a timestamp.

Comment: it's not a timestamp

Answer (score 21):

use `adb logcat -v threadtime`  in terminal to take the logs from device, it will include date and time.

if you want to redirect these logs into a text file then use command in terminal.

```
 adb logcat -v threadtime > folder_path_in_the_computer/filename.txt
```

Comment: Interesting is this gone now. in 2019 I get:

adb logcat -v threadtime

adb: usage: unknown command threadtime

Answer (score 9):

### Use `long`, `threadtime` or `time` formats with `logcat -v <format>`

[`logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) has a number of format options, which can be passed to the `-v` flag in the command line. You can view all of the formats in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#outputFormat).

Here are samples of what each option looks like so you can decide which one suits your needs:

---

#### `brief`

Display priority, tag, and PID of the process issuing the message.

```
D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1222): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1222): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `long`

Display all metadata fields and separate messages with blank lines.

*(I like this the best, but I'm a sucker for whitespace.)*

```
[ 01-27 13:17:07.703  1222: 1222 D/StatusBar.NetworkController ]
refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)

[ 01-27 13:17:07.703  1222: 1222 D/StatusBar.NetworkController ]
refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `process`

Display PID only.

```
D( 1222) refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)  (StatusBar.NetworkController)
D( 1222) refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)  (StatusBar.NetworkController)
```

---

#### `raw`

Display the raw log message with no other metadata fields.

```
refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `tag`

Display the priority and tag only.

```
D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `thread`

A legacy format that shows priority, PID, and TID of the thread issuing the message.

```
D( 1222: 1222) refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D( 1222: 1222) refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `threadtime`

Display the date, invocation time, priority, tag, PID, and TID of the thread issuing the message.

*(The docs say this is the default but not true in my case.)*

```
01-27 13:17:07.703  1222  1222 D StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
01-27 13:17:07.703  1222  1222 D StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

#### `time`

Display the date, invocation time, priority, tag, and PID of the process issuing the message.

```
01-27 13:17:07.703 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1222): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
01-27 13:17:07.703 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1222): refreshNwBoosterIndicator - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
```

---

**NOTE:** If you're using this in your app to programmatically collect your User's device logs to send to your support team or whatever, you need to omit the space between `-v` and the `format`, like so:

```
commandLine.add( "-vlong" )
```

Not sure why it's like that but hopefully that saves somebody time trying to figure that out.

Comment: Any way of getting the year along with date in "-v time" format? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) on the Developer Site:

"**time** — Display the date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the process issuing the message."

On the emulator it will be your computers time, on a device it will be time of your device...

Answer (score 0):

If you need the device date programmatically:

```
 SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String format = s.format(new Date());
```